# Can not apply Spark User defined Functions

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I've tried a lot of times to apply a function which applies some modification to a spark Dataframe which contains some text strings. Below is the corresponding code but it always give me this error:

> An error occurred while calling o699.showString.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 27.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 27.0 (TID 29, localhost, executor driver):

```
import os
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#!hdfs dfs -rm -r nixon_token*

spark = SparkSession.builder \
          .appName("spark-nltk") \
          .getOrCreate()

data = spark.sparkContext.textFile('1970-Nixon.txt')

def word_tokenize(x):
    import nltk
    return str(nltk.word_tokenize(x))
test_tok = udf(lambda x: word_tokenize(x),StringType())
resultDF = df_test.select("spans", test_tok('spans').alias('text_tokens'))
resultDF.show()
```

Comment: your sample is a bit confusing: what is `df_test` and how  do you use `data`? I can't see you're importing `udf` either..

Comment: check out this document: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-in-python.html

Comment: thanks Voldymyr i have found this tuto and it was helpful but seems the problems was from my data structure